# On a category of vector bundles. Does it look strange?

Tags: category-theory, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth compact manifold. Let say I want to define a category of vector bundles over $X$, where the objects are of the form $(E, g^E, \nabla^E)$ ($E\to X$ is a complex vector bundle, $g^E$ is a Hermitian metric and $\nabla^E$ is a unitary connection), and the morphisms are $T:(E, g^E, \nabla^E)\to(F, g^F, \nabla^F)$, where $T:E\to F$ is a **bundle isomorphism preserving the metrics**, i.e. $g^E=T^*g^F$. So an isomorphism between two objects is simply a morphism.

It seems to be mathematically correct to define such a category (correct me if it's not), but it looks awfully strange. Do we have other (popular) examples for which isomorphisms are morphisms?

Comment: Look up the term groupoid.

Comment: You can define it but it looks unnatural for several reasons. What is the motivation?

Comment: @LukasHeger Thanks. So what I defined is actually a groupoid. It's good that at least it is not something weird.

Comment: @MoisheKohan For some reason I am considering K-theory of this (believed to be a Banach category, but I haven't check) category. May I know the reasons you find it unnatural?